# Ошибка при selenium-server-standalone

Tags: php, тестирование, selenium

Пытаюсь установить *Selenium* сервер.

Установил глобально командой: `composer global require se/selenium-server-standalone`

Установилось нормально.
Далее выполняю: `selenium-server-standalone`

Выдает ошибку:

```
../se/selenium-server-standalone/composer/bin/selenium-server-standalone: line 11: java: command not found
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно установить java (и сделать это так, чтобы директория с исполняемым файлом попала в $PATH). Selenium - это java-приложение, и ошибка говорит вам о том, что не может найти java для запуска selenium.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Заработало)