# selenium-server-standalone . "sh" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: selenium, sh

Устанавливаю selenium аналогично ( [Ошибка при selenium-server-standalone](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479741/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-selenium-server-standalone) ), по статье http://krivochenko.ru/blog/post/introduction-to-testing-yii2

Пытаюсь установить Selenium сервер.

Установил глобально командой: `composer global require se/selenium-server-standalone`

Установилось нормально. Далее выполняю: `selenium-server-standalone`

на выходе получаю ошибку:

> "sh" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
>   программой или пакетным файлом.

http://clip2net.com/s/3udtm4B

Comment: В батнике написано:   @ECHO OFF
SET BIN_TARGET=%~dp0/../se/selenium-server-standalone/bin/selenium-server-standalone
sh "%BIN_TARGET%" %*

Comment: Может кому пригодится. Пришлось установить cydwin, прицепить его в Path,  запустить sh и в нём уже запустить через java  нужный скрипт.  Но решение так себе:(

Answer (score 1):

Так на Windows нет команды `sh`. Эта команда есть на `Unix` подобных системах.

> This can be simplified by creating a batch or shell executable file (.bat on Windows and .sh on Linux)

[proof](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp#running-selenium-server)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете запустить его сразу через java (собственно это и делает тот sh-скрипт)
Для этого нужно просто заменить содержимое bat файла на примерно вот такое:

```
:: C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin    
@ECHO OFF
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET BIN_TARGET=%~dp0/../se/selenium-server-standalone/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar
java -jar "%BIN_TARGET%" %*
```